# composer install error on post-autoload script

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Composer install give error on post-autoload-dump

Problem sudenly happens after composer update. Laravel app, running php 7.3 and IIS

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   @php artisan package:discover
>   Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code -1073741571

Comment: Are you running 'composer install' or 'composer update'? Do you have an .env file? Also, try updating your global dependencies, 'composer global update'.

Comment: @KarlHill running composer install;I tried composer global update and then composer install and the error persists

Comment: Can you post your composer.json?

Comment: Could you run `artisan package:discover` and post the error message it shows?

Comment: @PtrTon artisan package:discover  no error, problem persist

Comment: nothing?nobody?

Answer (score 0):

too long for response, add here
@KarlHill

`{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "Amranidev/scaffold-interface": "^1.7",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "genealabs/laravel-caffeine": "^0.8.1",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-i386": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "0.12.x",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "league/html-to-markdown": "^4.8",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mtownsend/request-xml": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Ceamsa\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Http/Helpers/ApiHelpers.php",
            "app/Http/Helpers/CertificateHelpers.php",
            "app/Http/Helpers/CommonHelpers.php",
            "app/Http/Helpers/CrudHelpers.php",
            "app/Http/Helpers/LanguageHelpers.php",
            "app/Http/Helpers/SapHelpers.php",
            "app/Http/Helpers/TemplateHelpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}`